# How to use READ ONLY transaction mode in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, sqlalchemy, readonly

In PostgreSQL transaction access mode can be changed to `READ ONLY` ([docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-set-transaction.html)). In SQLAlchemy, isolation level can be changed for an engine, but no parameter is provided for read-only access mode ([docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options.params.isolation_level)).

How to make an engine with `READ ONLY` access mode on connections?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One solution is to execute a statement on every transaction:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/')
@event.listens_for(engine, 'begin')
def receive_begin(conn):
    conn.execute('SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY')
```

But it's better to set mode in `BEGIN TRANSACTION` line an not a separate statement.

Answer (score 8):

With SQL Alchemy 1.4, it is possible to set readonly and deferrable mode using `Connection.execution_options()`.

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn = conn.execution_options(
        isolation_level="SERIALIZABLE",
        postgresql_readonly=True,
        postgresql_deferrable=True
    )
    with conn.begin():
        #  ... work with transaction
```

The above is an example taken from https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-readonly-deferrable

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient to create an engine by using [`create_engine()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine) together with [`execution_options()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.execution_options), because it allows to create an engine with readonly access mode (meaning that readonly is applied to all connections of that engine):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = (create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabase")
          .execution_options(postgresql_readonly=True))
```

Also possible is the following (found it in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#maintaining-multiple-isolation-levels-for-a-single-engine)):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabase",
                       execution_options={"postgresql_readonly": True})
```